# Get info from array with dynamic name and dynamic var

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get info from array with dynamic name and dynamic var?
Now I trying to get info from array with name, that store in `$command[0]` with var with name `$command[1]`. My code wont work.

```
$replacement_iterations = substr_count($pre_body, '*|');
var_dump($replacement_iterations);
$iteration_count = 0;
while($replacement_iterations > $iteration_count) {
   $command = explode(':', get_string_between($pre_body, "*|", "|*"));
   $replace_body = '*|' .  get_string_between($pre_body, "*|", "|*") . '|*';
   $put_body = $command[0].'[' . $command[1] . ']';
   var_dump($put_body);
   $pre_body = str_replace($replace_body, $command, $pre_body);
   var_dump($pre_body);
$iteration_count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use variable variables:

```
$myArray = ['a' => 'a', 'someVar' => 'samavar'];

$command = [
    'myArray',
    'someVar'
];

var_dump(
    ${$command[0]}[$command[1]]
);
// -> string(7) "samavar"
```